# Remote WMI, authing with domain account instead of local account

Tags: active-directory, dns, wmi

Written an app that grabs info of a specific computer using WMI remotely. Currently, I have to auth on each computer using one of the machine's local accounts. What I would like and what I'm trying to do is to be able to auth using a domain account (one of the accounts on the AD domain controller machine).

Right now, I can auth to domain machines only with local accounts with the exception of the domain controller. I can log on the AD DC using domain accounts by using NTLM protocol. The piece that isn't working is thus logging on to domain machines other than the DC using domain accounts.

Is this a code-issue or is it an AD setting issue, like I need to instruct the domain machines to always check with the DC when a user auths or something?

I'm using System.Managemnt.ManagementScope class in C# to handle all this curerently. Any help would be much appreciated.

I'm quite the newbie when it comes to AD and domains.

EDIT: Solved it.

Comment: Glad to hear you answered your question, and welcome to stackoverflow! If you could, please post your solution as an answer to the question, so that others who may be having similar problems can see what fixed things for you.

Comment: How did you solve it? I'm having the exact same issue, and your question is the only other place I can find this issue described.

Answer (score 0):

The Active Directory account in use needs to be given the permission called ["Trusted for Delegation"](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739764%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) in order to work on computers other than Domain Controllers. This right is extremely powerful, effectively allowing your account to present itself as *any* other account on the domain.

The alternative is to pass explicit permissions to the process. Bear in mind, though, that when connecting to another computer via WMI, the process created on the remote computer will *not* be able to authenticate to other computers on the domain; this is considered 3rd party delegation. There is a workaround to this limitation created by Frank White (on SO).